# Several issues with capturing a screen video with python

Tags: python, optimization

i have already asked a similar question on stackoverflow, but its not the same :-)
I have three problems with my code:

1. The framerate is not steady. When i execute the code without the screengrab, i still get low framerates, and whats worse, the framerate varies. I post output below. Any tips to fix this?
2. Its very slow. What this code will do is check for a pixel on the screen and record the time leading up to the occurrence of said pixel. Since there are potentially long pauses between records, i want to include a buffer that gets written in a worker thread, have not figured this out yet. Will this affect performance?
3. Sometimes it can happen that the pixel comes quickly after the first record. How do i prevent frameratedrops and how do i merge it with the other frames?

So here is my code:

```
import PIL.ImageGrab
import time

def get_pixel_colour(i_x, i_y):

    return PIL.ImageGrab.grab().load()[i_x, i_y]

print get_pixel_colour(0, 0)
fps = 5
skipticks = 1/(fps*1.0)
i= 0
allframes=[]
nextsnap=time.clock()
print skipticks, fps
while (True):
    tim= time.clock()
    i=i+1
    #x = PIL.ImageGrab.grab()
    # this prints the fps
    #'print 'Fps at start',i, 1/(time.time()-tim)
    #   x.save("tm\screengrab"+ str(i) +".jpg")
    # this is the sleep that limits the fps
    nextsnap+=skipticks
    # print nextsnap, skipticks
    sleeptime = nextsnap-time.clock()
    #print "want to sleep",sleeptime
    if (sleeptime>0):
        time.sleep (sleeptime)
    else:
        print 'took too long'
    print 'Fps at end:#', i, 1/(time.clock()-tim)
```

here is my output, when the screengrab is commented out:

```
Fps at end:# 1 4.93170511268
Fps at end:# 2 5.0171558081
Fps at end:# 3 5.43777363226
Fps at end:# 4 5.00931318904
Fps at end:# 5 5.00381624434
Fps at end:# 6 5.01183110503
Fps at end:# 7 5.01101022488
Fps at end:# 8 5.43623758467
Fps at end:# 9 5.04215239941
```

Here when it is not commented out:

```
Fps at end:# 13 5.05128838338
Fps at end:# 14 5.07528828608
Fps at end:# 15 5.51303968815
Fps at end:# 16 5.05357755475
Fps at end:# 17 5.0671482485
Fps at end:# 18 5.06788717279
Fps at end:# 19 5.06737062052
Fps at end:# 20 5.48886217371
Fps at end:# 21 5.067822598
```

i hope someone is able to help here :-)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We strictly improve working code, and it appears that your code is not in that category. If you want pointers on improving style/performance once it is working, please bring it back. I've migrated your question to StackOverflow where you are more likely to get help.

Comment: i have my code working now. can i repost it and ask for improvements from the community again?

Comment: @tarrasch Of course. :) If you have a specific question/problem you want resolved, ask on Stackoverflow. If it's a more broad "how can I clean this up/make it better?" question, then code review is the site to use.

Comment: ok, i will post the whole code, asking for improvements. i think there is always room to improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty, after looking around for a while, I've gotten these links together. First, this is similar to writing a refresh screen loop in a game. [Read this for some of the pitfalls with sleeping](http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/). For a better solution, you really want to have your program wait until the kernel updates the display, which *should* be a kernel event in linux. You'd do this by setting up a event queue with the [select library](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html#).

The only name I could find for the event queue to monitor [was here](http://wiki.xen.org/xenwiki/VirtualFramebuffer), with fbdev_evtchn as the channel. This may not apply.

If you find yourself on windows, or can't get notified of screen refreshes, then both the select library and the [signal library](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) have real-time timers. Those will give you an accurate wait, and depending on the implementation, should put the program under until the timer runs out.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for time.sleep

> time.sleep(secs)¶
>
> Suspend execution for the given number of seconds. The argument may be a floating point number to indicate a more precise sleep time.
>   The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any
>   caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that
>   signal’s catching routine. Also, the suspension time may be longer
>   than requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of
>   other activity in the system.

`time.sleep` is not an accurate timing mechanism. It'll usually end up sleeping for longer then you requested. The typical is solution is to sleep for a very short amount of time in a loop until enough time has passed.