# How to prevent subprocess.popen to "get lost" in Windows?

Tags: python, windows-7, subprocess, exe, popen

I have a somehow curious Python(3.x) problem:
Basically i just want to create a timer which calls an external program (.exe) at a predefined time - (simplified below, additionally there is a countdown output):

```
time.sleep(y)
x=popen("pathto.exe")
```

If i test my code everything works exactly as i want BUT only for small y. For large y (wait for more than a few hours), Python doesnt execute the popen command (but there arent any Errors as well). Any other "normal" code after the popen command (for example an Email notification in my case) works fine.

Im not entirely sure if this is a Windows (im working on 64bit Windows 7, disabled all energy saving features im aware of) or a Python problem but couldnt find a solution so far:
I tried several additional arguments for popen (Shell/no Shell, etc.) and tried to open the program/define X ahead of the waiting period and close it afterwards again but nothing solved this unfortunately.

Many Thanks!

Edit: more detailed code example:

```
while 1:
    if time.mktime(trade2)<=time.time():

        break

    else:
        dif=time.mktime(trade2)-time.time()  # this is just for a visible countdown
        aus=time.gmtime(dif)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        print("\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b", end="\r")
        print(aus[3],aus[4],aus[5], sep=":",end="")
        time.sleep(0.5)

x=subprocess.Popen("c:/xyz/abc.exe")
print("Sending Mail...")
```

The print() is ALWAYS executed as expected, the Popen only when the countdown less than approx 1-2hours.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `time.sleep()`?

Comment: what happens if you replace popen call by a print?

Comment: With a print (and any other "internal" command), everything works as expected...  As i said, after the popen command i have some code to send a confirmation mail - that works flawlessy even if the "sleep time" is very long. The popen command just seems to be skipped...

Comment: Probably some code to tell the program to "stay active" (prevent any Windows Idle measures?) and reserve memory for calling of external programs could be a solution? (But in general there is always enough ram available, no memory leaks..)

Answer (score 1):

Sleep does not have a guaranteed wake up time. [According to the docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/time.html#time.sleep) sleep may last a longer or shorter amount of time than requested. I've [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8403434/724357) this question before on SO, with alternatives.

Comment: But the time is definitely not the problem. As i wrote, all other code except "popen" works fine and is executed exactly when the sleep expired!   -  EDIT: in fact, im using a shorter sleep command in a loop, so the description above was just to shorten the explanation of my problem - sorry.

Comment: @jpdus popen is insidiously difficult to work with. Reread the docs, and make sure all of your flags are set appropriately. Also check which version of popen you are using. Finally, look into [envoy](https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy) for easier subprocess functionality.

Comment: As i stated above, i already tried almost all documentated flags (buffersize, close_fds, shell) but the problem stays.. everything works if the sleep time is only short but after long periods, Python seems to be unable to call an external program... If envoy is just a subprocess wrapper, i doubt that it will help because i dont really need any interaction with the subprocess, i just need the program to be called.

Comment: @jpdus popen just starts a subprocess. It does not interact with it, or even wait until it completes. So how do you know if the process is doing anything with a short timer?

Comment: Well, i just try to open another program (via path to an .exe file). With a short timer, the program opens exactly as i want it, with a long timer the popen command is just skipped (but all other code after the timer works as before). Sorry if that wasnt clear enough.

Comment: @jpdus That makes no sense at all. It should work. Have you tried running a different executable? Also, could you post a more complete code snippet? It may be a problem somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Yep it should work and that is why im a bit desperate.. dont know how to isolate the error!  Edited the question with a more complete snippet.

Comment: @jpdus You aren't truly sleeping, because your sleep only lasts .5 seconds. Then your program wakes up, checks the time, prints a countdown, and waits .5 more seconds. That's entirely different from calling `time.sleep(5 hours)`. As I noted previously, popen just starts the child proc and then the main thread continues. If the main thread prints then closes, *it could kill children too*. See if you can pause the main thread, and check your running processes for `abc.exe`.

Comment: I can pause the mainthread, this changes nothing. Everything behaves the same + as expected when changing the countdown timefrime, except the Popen command gets somhow "skipped" - its really weird and i have no real explanation. Probably really a windows problem? But many thanks already!

Comment: @jpdus so when you paused the main thread after the popen command, did you see the `abc` process running? If not, then you may have hit a bug inside subprocess, as it should tell you it failed to start the child, or a windows error.

Comment: With "long" countdown: process not running, no Python error, no windows error / with "short" countdown: process running

Comment: @jpdus try using `subprocess.call()` instead of popen.

Comment: unfortunately that doesnt change anything as well. I noticed a few more details etc. an posted a follow-up question now, many thanks so far! : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123165/windows-7-vista-process-management-how-to-start-an-external-program-after-long)