# Windows 7/Vista process management - how to start an external program after long idle time?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, windows-7, process

This is a follow-up to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882582/how-to-prevent-subprocess-popen-to-get-lost-in-windows) question.

Basically, i have a python script which should start another program (.exe) via a timer after some 2-6 hours. Everything works fine as long as i test it with a short countdown or as long as the computer is "active" (=userinput before, screen on) before the timer expires or as long there is no other program working at the same time (an Excel VBA script in my case).

On Windows 7, for long countdowns and with Excel running, the external program just doesnt open. There arent any Error messages and any other (python-internal) commands AFTER that are executed as they should.

Im using the **`x=subprocess.Popen([program,args],flags)`** command and tried almost all possible flags (Shell, buffersize, creationflags,stdout etc.) and alternatives (call) but it behaves always as described above.

Now i noticed a similar behaviour when trying to open the external program via VBA, so i dont think its a Python-specific but a Windows-specific problem. Additionally i tried it on another PC with Windows Vista and there it works surprisingly (both 64-bit if that matters).

I already tried increasing the process priority or prevent idle state via [SetThreadExecutionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and disabled all energy-saving features i´am aware of, but nothing changed so far.

Does anyone have an idea? Many thanks, im getting frustrated slowly...

Comment: Are you subprocessing excel? Have you considered moving that functionality inside your python script? Using open office? Or, connecting to excel with COM?

Comment: @Spencer no the Excel vba macro is not connected in any way with my script (except that it has to run at the same time, which works fine). I additionally tried to open the external program after the "excel-timer" via VBA and ran into the same problem... Python/VBA "internal" commands are executed as they should after the respective timers but it is not possible to open an external program...

Comment: Have you tried moving to a fresh machine? Maybe something on your system is borked.

Comment: @Spencer Dont think so, i tried 3 machines  so far, 2 different laptops (both Windows 7, 32bit+64bit) and one PC with Vista - on both laptops the same issue, it works just on the PC with Vista... so im convinced it has something to do with windows process management / energy saving / probably some new Windows 7 feature..

Comment: That sounds depressingly likely. But it also sounds like it has something to do with the executable you are trying to subprocess. How hard would it be to migrate that functionality into the python script? Barring that, check out [winpdb](http://winpdb.org/). See if you can hook the debugger into your script, and then set up a break point just before the subprocess call.

Comment: This is a dupe of your other question. Why don't you use the task scheduler?

Comment: @David: In my opinion it isnt.. The "old" question was related to Python while im now relatively sure its a Windows/Service problem. So i dont see your reason for downvoting here? But im still new to StackOverflow, probably you can explain me how to handle my problem better here.... thanks!

Comment: It's the same question. The fact that you originally thought the issue was with the Python code, and you are now suspecting it is the fault of Windows, does not change the fact that the question is the same.

Comment: I still don't understand why you don't use the task scheduler. If you want to solve your current program you will need to insert some debugging/logging diagnostics code into your Python code.

Comment: @David: Use of the task scheduler could be a possible workaround, but i have no idea how debugging/logging diagnostics could help me (as i stated serveral times, everything except the Popen statement executes properly and on time). But why you dont just submit an answer with your proposal instead of downvoting/complaining in the comments? Would have closed the "old" question if i knew how - Editing everything would render all comments there senseless..

Comment: I'm trying to help. But you don't seem receptive.

Comment: @David: I dont see much help from you here ... the question was "Windows7/Vista process management - how to start an external program after long idle time?" and i have still no idea how to do that or why my code works in Vista and not in Win7.. but at least the task scheduler is an idea for a workaround, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After taking account the problem stated in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882582/how-to-prevent-subprocess-popen-to-get-lost-in-windows), I think a viable alternative would be to 
use many short pauses instead of a long pause, so the program is always active, but may result in higher memory usage.

```
def wait(sec,sleeptime = 0):
    import time
    endsecs = time.time() + sec
    while True:
        if endsecs <= time.time():
            return None
        if sleeptime != 0:
            time.sleep(sleeptime)
```

Just a guess, nothing certain, no time to verify.

Comment: Hm, i experimented with different "sleep" intervals but still didnt find any viable solution. For the time being im stuck with using Vista instead of Win7...

Comment: Yes! I tried basically everything and many intervals. The error only occures if the countdown is longer than about 1-2hours and the PC is "untouched" during that time. Any code except the "Popen" statement executes as expected. If i move the mouse (or hit any key or whatever) before the countdown expires everything (including the Popen) works.

Comment: what if you call a popen just to interrupt the timer?  As in calling some program every 30 minutes?